# MySQL count 6 combination duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores 6 values in 6 columns

How can I get a count of the amount of rows where these 6 values are completely identical?

My current query =

```
select item_0,item_1,item_2,item_3,item_4,item_5 from games_player_stats where champion_id = :c '.$query_role.' group by item_0,item_1,item_2,item_3,item_4,item_5
```

The total amount of records found with the champion / role search `filter = 2272`

The amount of unique combinations found `2262`

This is obviously not working but I can't seem to figure out how to use the group by in this situation

Comment: What do you mean by "completely identical"?  What do you want returned?

Answer (score 0):

use `SUM` or `Group by` like that :-

```
select 
sum(item_0)+sum(item_1)+sum(item_2)+sum(item_3)+sum(item_4)+sum(item_5) 
from games_player_stats 
where champion_id = :c '.$query_role.' 
group by item_0,item_1,item_2,item_3,item_4,item_5
```

Comment: This is not correct. It is even wrong to aggregate over fields you group by. The Asker wanted records where the 6 values are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all entries where item_0 = item_1 = ... = item_5, then you could check for that :

```
'select item_0,count(*) 
from games_player_stats 
where champion_id = :c '.$query_role.' 
and item_0=item_1 and item_0=item_2 and item_0=item_3 and item_0=item_4 and item_0=item_5
group by item_0'
```

If you aren't interested in the individual counts for the different values of item_0, omit the GROUP BY